# A standard deck of 52 cards has four queens. Two cards are randomly drawn in succession, without replacement.

Tags: probability, statistics

A.) What is the probability that the first card is a queen?

B.) What is the probability that the second card is a queen?

C.) If three cards are drawn, what is the probability that the third card is a queen?

My answer is that
a.) 4/52
b.) 3/51
c.) 46C1/48C3

Are my answers correct? Can I also use the combination formula to solve for question A and B?

Comment: Combinations disregard order, but these questions care about the order (first, second, third, etc).  So, I would avoid combinations.

Comment: Do you think you could include the work you did to get you to those answers? That would better help us help you and others.

Comment: All answers must be $4/52$.

Comment: I get it now. The second answer was 3/51 because I assumed the first card was a queen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four queens in the deck, and any one of them is equally likely to be anywhere in the deck.   Queens don't rise to the top or whatever; there is no bias.

> > A.) What is the probability that the first card is a queen?
>
> My answer is that a.) 4/52

Yes.  Any particular card could be on top with the same probability.  Four of the fifty two are queens.

> > B.) What is the probability that the second card is a queen?
>
> My answer is that b.) 3/51

That is the *conditional* probability that the second card is a queen *when given that* the first is.  You have not been given that condition.

Any particular card could be the second card in the deck with the same probability.   Four of the fifty-two cards are queens.   Therefore probability that the second card is a queen, equals:...

> > C.) If three cards are drawn, what is the probability that the third card is a queen?
>
> My answer is that c.) 46C1/48C3

I... cannot work out from what hat you are plucking these numbers.

Any particular card could be the third card drawn with the same probability.   Four of the fifty-two cards are queens.   Therefore probability that the third of three cards drawn is a queen, equals:...

Answer (score 0):

A) is correct.

For B) you seem to assume that the first card was definitely a queen, but you don't know that. So, for B), you may want to consider two cases: that the first card was a queen, and that the first card was not a queen.

Do something similar for C)